# Why doesn't the FutureBuilder return data queried from Sqlite database?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to query the to-dos stored in sqlite database as a list. I used a FutureBuilder to retrieve the list, but it doesn't seem to return the value. It shows an error like "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null."

This is my database provider:

```
    class MemoDbProvider{
  Database db;

  MemoDbProvider(){
    init();
  }

  void init() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path,"memos.db");

      db = await openDatabase(
        path,
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database newDb,int version){
          newDb.execute("""
          CREATE TABLE Memos(
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          title TEXT,
          content TEXT)"""
      );
    });
  }

  Future<int> addItem(MemoModel item){
    return db.insert("Memos", item.toMap(),
    conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.ignore,
    );
  }

  Future<List<MemoModel>> fetchMemos() async{
    final maps = await db.query("Memos");

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return MemoModel(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        title: maps[i]['title'],
        content: maps[i]['content'],
      );
  });
  }
}
```

This is the MemoList Widget:

```
class MemoList extends StatefulWidget{
  createState(){
    return MemoListState();
  }
}

class MemoListState extends State<MemoList>{
  MemoDbProvider dbProvider = MemoDbProvider();

  Widget build(context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Memo'),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addMemo');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: dbProvider.fetchMemos(),
        builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<MemoModel>> snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            print('error');
          }
          print(snapshot.data);
            return ListView.builder(
            itemCount : snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,int index){
              return buildMemo(snapshot.data[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),  
    );
  }

  Widget buildMemo(MemoModel memo){
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          onTap: (){},
          title: Text(memo.title),
          subtitle: Text(memo.content),
        ),
        Divider(
          height: 8.0,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When i press the FloatingActionButton(/addMemo) it works and print the memo list in terminal. When i go back to MemoList i can properly see the list. Why isn't it rendering at the startup?
Since i am new to flutter it would be great if i get a fine explanation on the issue in my code.

Comment: add final db = await database; line in fetchMemos method as first line. i this it you did not created object.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya The answer is not clear. I haven't declared anything called database.

Comment: in MemoDbProvider class you created global db variable, but did not initialised it. so it want you to add final db = await database; line as fetchMemos method's first, which initialise db correctly.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I have initialised db in the init() method which is called in the constructor of MemoDbProvider. Is it wrong?

Comment: no it is not wrong.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya Thanks for the guidance. It worked when initialised db as you told. I am using the init() method to initialise db instead of calling it in constructor. Great if you could submit your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating object of db but not initialising it, because of that you are getting this error.

To solve this error, you can create object in method because it is async, so you can not even create at class level.

Create db variable as following.

```
final db = await database;
```